# How to use Html5 tags e.g email with struts2

Tags: struts2

I am using `struts2` for presentation layer, now there is requirement to use `html5` tags e.g. email, tel etc., but it seems that `struts2` doesn't support `html5` tags.

Is there any way to achieve the above requirement?

Comment: *it seems that struts2 doesn't support html5 tags* why do you think so? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can add custom (HTML5 and others) attributes to Struts2 Tags that have declared they support Dynamic Attributes. Look [in the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/textfield.html), for each tag you are using, under the `Parameters` part if you see `Dynamic Attributes Allowed: true`;
2. You can still use native HTML elements, along with Struts tags. Then both the following ways are good:

```xml
<s:textfield name="foo" value="bar" customAttr />

<input type="text" name="foo" value="<s:property value="bar"/>" customAttr />
```

If you need to change the `type`, you can now do it with the Struts `<s:textfield />` tag too:

```xml
<s:textfield type="email"    name="foo" value="bar" customAttr />

<s:textfield type="date"     name="foo" value="bar" customAttr />

<s:textfield type="currency" name="foo" value="bar" customAttr />
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

Your struts2 tags(`<s: >`) will finally be converted to basic HTML tags when the page is rendered, which you can check by looking into the generated source. Usually, Struts2 just adds some css(if you are not using `theme="simple"`) to the basic HTML tags. So. it is incorrect to say that

> struts2 doesn't support html5 tags

Use the Html5 tags as usual, they will work. 
It looks like you are new to the community, so dont get demotivated by the downvotes but in future try to do some homework and ask specific problems, what did you try and what did not work

Comment: there is a HTML5 tag <input type="email"> or <input type="tel">, what is the Struts equivalent for this?

Comment: According to my knowledge there are no such struts2 equivalent tags yet for these. But why do you need it, you can always use these HTML tags within your struts2 form?

Comment: I am using modeldriven feature in struts2 to pre-populate the values for the fields like email, phone etc. from model. and this can only work with struts2 tags. With html tags it is not possible pre-populate values for these fields from model.

Comment: In that case why dont you try this `<input type="email" value="<s:property value="whatever"/>">`